# Why does my husband's Gmail account pop up when I try to sign in to YouTube?

Tags: gmail, youtube, account-management

Two to three weeks ago, my husband's computer wasn't working, so I let him use my tablet. Since then we've been receiving each other's emails etc. He changed his password to try and fix the problem, but now it's not allowing me to sign in to YouTube etc. It tells me to sign in, but shows his Gmail account and asks for his password! What is up with that?

Comment: You mention a tablet. Are you using an Android tablet, perhaps, and the native applications? I'm afraid that questions here should be about the web interface. The simple answer is is to remove your husband's credentials from the "Accounts" section of your settings.

Answer (score 1):

There should be an option to sign in with a different account on Google's login page.

[image: Google's login page]

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, your husband didn't log out from gmail. This keeps him logged to any google owned website such as Youtube, Gmail and Google. Sign in with a different account as [Steven proposes](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/105849/60818).